# Why doesn't sort this code the German words?

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to sort German words with their articles, but it don't work perfectly. Can you help me?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
struct asd
{
    string ne;
    string fn;
};
int main()
{
    asd szavak[50];
    ifstream be("nemet.txt");
    int db=0;
    while (!be.eof())
    {
        be>>szavak[db].ne;
        be>>szavak[db].fn;
        cout<<szavak[db].ne<< " "<<szavak[db].fn<<endl;
        db++;
    }
    be.close();
    cout<< "\n\n"<< "Rendezve:\n";
    for (int i=0; i<db-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j<db; j++)
        {
            if (szavak[j].ne<szavak[i].ne)
            {
                swap(szavak[j].ne,szavak[i].ne);
                swap(szavak[j].fn,szavak[i].fn);
            }
        }
    }
    int sv1=0;
    int sv2=0;
    int sv3=0;
    for (int i=0; i<db; i++)
    {
        if (szavak[i].ne=="das")
        {
            sv1++;
        }
        if (szavak[i].ne=="der")
        {
            sv2++;
        }
        if (szavak[i].ne=="die")
        {
            sv3++;
        }
    }
    for (int j=0; j<sv1-1; j++)
    {
        for (int k=j+1; k<sv1; k++)
        {
            if (szavak[k].fn<szavak[j].fn)
            {
                swap(szavak[k].fn,szavak[j].fn);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int h=sv1; h<sv1+sv2-1; h++)
    {
        for (int f=h+1; f<sv2; f++)
        {
            if (szavak[f].fn<szavak[h].fn)
            {
                swap(szavak[f].fn,szavak[h].fn);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int s=sv1+sv2; s<sv1+sv2+sv3-1; s++)
    {
        for (int l=s+1; l<sv3; l++)
        {
            if (szavak[l].fn<szavak[s].fn)
            {
                swap(szavak[l].fn,szavak[s].fn);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<db; i++)
    {
        cout<<szavak[i].ne<< " "<<szavak[i].fn<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expected it to sort the words correctly after 'das' too, but it didn't.

Here are the words that I used in the txt(one word in one line):

```
der Hafen
die Anzeige
das Einfamilienhaus
das Mehrfmilienhaus
der Mitbewohner
die Miete
die Badewanne
das Badezimmer
das Wohnzimmer
die Aussicht
das Arbeitszimmer
die Decke
der Plattenbau
der Altbau
der Neubau
der Hund
das Zimmer
das Bild
der Spiegel
die Kindern
die Waschmaschine
```

Comment: You may want to show us the results you've got, rather than just saying that you don't like them.

Comment: Your sorting implementation is wrong. Are you trying to do bubble sort? Then compare `[j]` and `[j-1]` ...

Comment: Why do you expect it to be sorted by `fn` if your bubble sort doesn't ever check `fn`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't checked the validity of your code *(it's a bit hard to read)*, but you should always resort to the algorithms supplied by the standard library *(unless of course you want to learn how to write sorting algorithms)*. This helps to prevent bugs like this. In your case you can use the `std::sort` algorithm if you provide a comparison function for `asd` which only compares `ne`.

### Sorting based on `ne`

The following example provides the comparison function in form of a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

```cpp
std::sort(
    std::begin(szavak), 
    std::end(szavak), 
    [](asd const& a, asd const& b){ return a.ne < b.ne; }
);
for (auto const& a : szavak){
    std::cout << a.ne << " " << a.fn << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
das Einfamilienhaus
das Mehrfmilienhaus
das Badezimmer
das Wohnzimmer
das Bild
das Arbeitszimmer
das Zimmer
der Hafen
der Mitbewohner
der Spiegel
der Plattenbau
der Altbau
der Neubau
der Hund
die Waschmaschine
die Kindern
die Decke
die Aussicht
die Badewanne
die Miete
die Anzeige
```

See [here for a live code example](https://godbolt.org/z/dhxjvhdc3)

### Sorting first by `ne`, then by `fn`

If you want to sort first by article, then by noun, you can wrap `ne` and `fn` in tuples using [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie). tuples are by default compared [lexicographically](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp)

```cpp
std::sort(
    std::begin(szavak), 
    std::end(szavak), 
    [](asd const& a, asd const& b){ 
        return std::tie(a.ne, a.fn) < std::tie(b.ne, b.fn); 
    }
);
```

Output:

```
das Arbeitszimmer
das Badezimmer
das Bild
das Einfamilienhaus
das Mehrfmilienhaus
das Wohnzimmer
das Zimmer
der Altbau
der Hafen
der Hund
der Mitbewohner
der Neubau
der Plattenbau
der Spiegel
die Anzeige
die Aussicht
die Badewanne
die Decke
die Kindern
die Miete
die Waschmaschine
```

See [here for a live code example](https://godbolt.org/z/1K4T556EW)

### Bubble sort

If you *do* want to learn how to write a sorting algorithm, I would start by assuming that you have a comparison function for the elements in your array that returns `true`, if two elements are in order and `false` otherwise. Then you write your sorting algorithm with the use of this comparison function.

This makes your sorting algorithm more general, as you could pass in any comparison function you like. In addition, you can concentrate on the algorithm itself without having to worry about the types of objects that you are sorting or the criterium by which you are sorting them.

A simple [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) implementation based on [forward iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/forward_iterator) and a callable `Comparator` object could look like this:

```cpp
template <typename ForwardIt, typename Comparator>
void sort(ForwardIt begin, ForwardIt end, Comparator const& comp)
{
    bool is_sorted = false;
    while (!is_sorted){
        is_sorted = true; // assume the container is sorted for now
        ForwardIt current = begin;
        ForwardIt next = current;
        ++next;
        while(next != end){
            if (!comp(*current, *next)) {
                /* swap them and remember something changed */
                std::iter_swap(current, next);
                is_sorted = false;
            }
            ++current;
            ++next;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the implementation makes no assumption on the type of objects in the array and no assumption on the criterium by which they shall be sorted. You only use

- an iterator `current` pointing to an element in the list that can be incremented to obtain the `next` element in the list
- [`std::iter_swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) to swap the values that two iterators point to.
- A templated `Comparator` function, which must be invokable on two const references to objects in the list and return a `bool`.

See [here for a live code example](https://godbolt.org/z/3dzva6WWh)